# Error: cannot access android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working on Android application in which to make header file I am using terminal. For this I am using the following commands should in the images but getting the following errors:

```
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:MUrgency_with_JNI UsmanKhan$ javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.ziqitza.helper.HelloJni
Error: cannot access android.app.Activity
  class file for android.app.Activity not found
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:MUrgency_with_JNI UsmanKhan$
```

[image]
[image: By accessing to the classes through bin i am getting all of the class names in that particular package]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you need to specify the path to the android.jar, which is usually located under `sdk/platforms/android-version`

```
javah -jni -classpath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-version/android.jar:bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.ziqitza.helper.HelloJni
```

or with

```
javah -jni -bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-version/android.jar  -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.ziqitza.helper.HelloJni
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works like a charm. i was giving  a wrong path to sdk